# Presenting a PHP file as an extensionless file or folder in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Previously, the server allowed me to reference to any PHP file without an extension. I've tried playing with `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess`.

Unfortunately, looks like my htaccess-fu has been drained, and I can't get it to work with subfolders. I can redirect `staticfilename.css`, but not `static/filename.css`.

---

**Q:** Given a (virtual) folder `static/` and the PHP script `static.php` which can handle `static.php/filename.css`, what is the **easiest** way to get Apache2 to load `static.php/filename.css` for URL `static/filename.css`?

`.htaccess`-only solutions are preferred. But, if needed, I can make virtualhost-specific or server-wide changes as well.

---

Putting this in the `<VirtualHost>` helped, but I feel terrible about having such a stanza which is specific to a single site, to a single file.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/static/(.*)$ $1/static.php/$2 [P]
```

Hence, I'd still love to figure out a way to redirect other similar files: a script I called `davrun.php`, for example, handles WebDAV in a different site on the same server, and fixing this in either a more universal way (or in a per-`.htaccess`-usable way)  would allow for providing more natural paths in that script as well.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/static/(.*)$ $1/static.php/$2` - OMG! why you need to have a php file to served static contents

Comment: @silentboy An old piece of code -- a hack to add proper caching headers. In any case, as noted, this has more uses than just serving static files: WebDAV comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ /static.php/$1 [L]
```

(I suppose you know how to load static.php using /static.php/filename.css)